# When to use functions and when to use messages

Tags: objective-c

I am really feeling like a nube today, i didn't realise Objective-C had functions - I simply thought that you always use to use messages!

When should one use functions and when should one use messages?

For example if I am creating a object within my class should I use a function?

Comment: Are you asking about "methods" or "messages"? Your title and body confuse me.

Comment: Objective-C functions are really C functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objective-C is a strict superset of C, so anything you can do in C you can do in Objective-C, including functions.

Even though you can, technically, use functions for *everything* in Objective-C, you shouldn't. Clarity should be your first concern and writing classes that are a mixture of methods and functions is confusing. Strive to emulate the APIs that you are using. If you're writing `UIKit` code, stick with methods only. If you're doing drawing in `Core Graphics`, use functions.

If you aren't sure, use methods. If you're creating an object in your class use methods.